# Как запомнить состояние дерева?

Tags: php, javascript, yii

Есть такая задачка - запомнить состояние дерева. Думаю писать в сессию. Отсюда имеем - нужно js узнать стиль объекта.

```
console.log(document.getElementById('13').classList.contains('open'));
```

И каким-то образом передать в контролер, а там в массив сохранить. Очень смутное представление как это сделать.

Проблемка еще в чем,

```
<ul>
<li id="13" class="closed expandable">
<li id="45" class="closed expandable">
<li id="6" class="closed expandable">
<li id="2" class="closed expandable lastExpandable">
<div class="hitarea closed-hitarea collapsable-hitarea lastCollapsable-hitarea"></div>
<a class="" href="/proizvodstvo/site/page?view=frameset&frame=2">страница</a>
<ul style="display: block;">
```

То есть у хитарея нет идентификатора дива, но он есть у `li`. Как можно обратиться к предку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятный вопрос, сохранить на сервере? Просто передайте туда id раскрытых узлов. А на сервере при обращении к дереву просто выполняйте поиск по id попутно раскрывая узлы содержащие его

вот например

```
.1  
..1.1  
..1.2  
...1.2.1  
....1.2.1.1
....1.2.1.2
...1.2.2  
..1.3  
.2
..2.1
.3
```

Передаете в конроллер [1.2.1, 2]

А если надо получить родительский элемент гуглите jquey parents

Answer (score 1):

Так в чем проблема? Получите дом как строку и сохраните. Нативно я не помню как это сделать, но у jQuery есть метод `html` он вернет строку.
Но я бы не советовал сохранять дом. Лучше отделить представление от данных и сохранять данные, а по ним заново строить DOM.

Answer (score 1):

цель сохранения? если "на всегда" то на сервере, как посоветовали выше. если на какое-то время - можно в localStorage.